# Maximization Lemma in Matrix Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I am having a problem with understanding an English sentence underlined in red below. Can somebody let me understand what it is saying? and what is maximized?

[image]

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1226455/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is saying two things.

1. Since for all $x \neq 0$ we have $\frac{(x'd)^2}{x'Bx} \leq d'B^{-1} d$, then also $\displaystyle\max_{x\neq0} \frac{(x'd)^2}{x'Bx} \leq d'B^{-1} d$.
2. For the particular choice of $x = cB^{-1}d$ (for any $c \neq 0$), we have $\frac{(x'd)^2}{x'Bx} = d'B^{-1} d$, and so $\displaystyle\max_{x\neq0} \frac{(x'd)^2}{x'Bx} \geq d'B^{-1} d$.

These two things put together imply that $$\max_{x\neq0} \frac{(x'd)^2}{x'Bx} = d'B^{-1} d.$$

Comment: What does max x mean? I an sorry I still don't get what we are maximizing. I am sorry for asking something really primitive...

Comment: It denotes taking the maximum of the quantity to the right over all possible values of $x$ (in this case, all non-zero vectors of the correct format).

Comment: Is it possible to have an example? It is way very abstract to me... If it is too way too much, please don't waste your time. I am still happy with whatever I got from you.

Comment: Try taking $B = I$ and see what happens.

Comment: Here's an example of the max notation:
$$
\max_{x \in [0,1]} x(1-x) = \frac 14
$$